# How do I create a templated template specialization of a function in c++/c++20?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++20

I have written my own fixed point numeric class which is intended to be used like `float` or `double`:

```
template<typename T, unsigned Precision> struct fixed {...}
```

`T` must be `int8_t`, `int16_`t, `int32_t` or `int64_t` and it will use `Precision` bits for the fractional part. There is no exponent part. I have implemented the necessary operators, conversion operators etc. and everything is working as expected.

Now I want to use this class with boost qvm and create 3 dimensional vectors of my fixed class:

```
using fixed_vec3 = boost::qvm::vec<fixed<int32_t, 10>, 3>;
auto my_vec3 = fixed_vec3{1.25, 2.5, 3.75};
```

So far, so good. But if I try to get the magnitude of the vector I run into a little problem:

```
auto my_mag = mag(my_vec3);
```

obviously yields a linker error, I am missing the `sqrt` method specialization which is defined in namespace `boost::qvm` and used by the `mag(...)` method in `boost::qvm`:

```
namespace boost::qvm {
...
    template <class T> T sqrt( T );
...
    template <> BOOST_QVM_INLINE_TRIVIAL float sqrt<float>( float x ) { return ::sqrtf(x); }
...
    template <> BOOST_QVM_INLINE_TRIVIAL double sqrt<double>( double x ) { return ::sqrt(x); }
...
}
```

I have my own implementation for `sqrt`:

```
template<typename T, unsigned Precision>
fixed<T, Precision> sqrt(fixed<T, Precision> val)
{
    return ...;
}
```

How can I create a specialization of `boost::qvm::sqrt` for my templated `fixed` class? The following already works perfectly for a specific specialization of `fixed`:

```
namespace ::boost::qvm {
template<>
inline fixed<int32_t, 10>
sqrt<fixed<int32_t, 10>>(fixed<int32_t, 10> value)
{
  return ...
}
}
```

Note: inside the `mag` method in `boost::qvm` the method `sqrt` is called like this:

```
...
    T const m2=a0*a0+a1*a1+a2*a2;
    T const mag=sqrt<T>(m2);
    return mag;
...
```

However I would of course like to create a templated version for all possible `fixed` templates, not the one for `fixed<int32_t, 10>` resp. enumerate them all. Overloads of course don't work because of the explicit reference to the template with one parameter. Is this even possible in this case? How do I do this (without changing the boost source code of course)?

By the way: I am using Visual Studio 2019, the Microsoft C++ compiler, using C++ 20 resp. "latest working draft c++".

Comment: It doesn’t solve your problem, but Boost shouldn’t provide that explicit template argument—moreover it should do the normal thing of forwarding through a class template that can handle the partial specializations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using c++20. Consider the following template function `my_sqrt`.

```
template<class T>
T my_sqrt(T x);
```

Full specialization is straightforward (e.g. for double).

```
template<>
double my_sqrt(double x) { return sqrt(x); }
```

Partial specialization can be implemented using a `requires` clause that constrains the type (e.g. for any std::pair).

```
template<class T>
requires is_same_template_v<T, std::pair>
T my_sqrt(T p) {
    return std::make_pair(sqrt(p.first), sqrt(p.second));
}
```

Where `is_same_template_v` determines if the type is a realization of the given template:

```
template<class T, class U, template<class...> class V>
struct is_same_template : std::false_type
{ static constexpr bool value = false; };

template<template<class...> class T, template<class...> class U, class... Ts>
struct is_same_template<T<Ts...>, U<Ts...>, U>
{
    using type = std::true_type;
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<T<Ts...>,U<Ts...>>;
};

template<class T, template<class...> class U>
using is_same_template_t = typename is_same_template<T,T,U>::type;

/**
 * @brief Is class T a realization of template U?
 *
 * @tparam T the class to test
 * @tparam U the template to compare
 */
template<class T, template<class...> class U>
static constexpr bool is_same_template_v = is_same_template<T,T,U>::value;
```

For your use case, I think the code would look something like:

```
namespace ::boost::qvm {
template<class T>
requires is_same_template_v<T, fixed>
T sqrt(T value)
{
  return ...
}
}
```

Disclaimer: I am using clang-11 and do not have access to VS.